# Rendering state in v-for without setting the state in array [vue]

Tags: vue.js

I'm rendering a list of emails with v-for that can be removed by an admin. I need to set a state of 'Loading' to be true or false based on if the process of removing an email is happening or not. I know if I used an object I could add a property of loading into the object and set that state in my remove function but is it possible to set a state of one of my list items while keeping the list as an array of strings?

```
data: {
   admins: [foo@gmail.com, bar@gmail.com]
}

<div class="admin-row" :class="{active : editAdmins}" v-for="(admin, index) in admins" :key="index">
   <div class="remove-admin">
      <fa v-if="!loading" @click="removeAdmin(admin)" icon="minus-circle"/>
      <fa v-if="loading" class="remove-admin-loader" icon="spinner" spin/>
   </div>
</div>
```

So basically I want to set the loading variable to true when removeAdmin is clicked but I need the variable to be scoped in the v-for statement.

Comment: Do you want a single `loading` value that applies to all of the `<fa>` components, or does each component have a separate state? If the former, just define the variable as data and use it within the loop; there's no need to worry about scope. If the latter, then of course you'll need a separate property for each element. BTW, you might find `v-else` to be somewhat cleaner than your current construction.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have to either create another array with the loading variables that preserve the same order of elements as the admins array and then set the loadings[index] variable or change the array of admins to an array of objects instead of an array of strings. In this case the array of admins should seem something like this:

```
admins: [
    {mail: 'foo@gmail.com', loading: false},
    {mail: 'bar@gmail.com', loading: true}
]
```

Comment: yeah that's kind of what I figured, I was hoping there was a more basic solution, thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the contents in the array are strings and you can't directly add properties into a string.

To solve that, we need to create a simple class which wraps the `string` into an `object` and the secret lies in the [`toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) method.

```
class StringObject {
    constructor(value) {
        this.value = value;
  }

  toString() {
    return this.value;
  }
}
```

And on the `removeAdmin`, add a condition to convert the string into a `StringObject`:

```
if (!(this.admins[index] instanceof StringObject)) {
    this.$set(this.admins, index, new StringObject(this.admins[index]))
}
```

Now, in the template you can use it as:

```
{{ admin.toString() }}
```

Just check the whole working sample here: https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/235969/

**Though this will serve as an answer your question, I wouldn't recommend this approach as it just adds more complexity to your code and also this doesn't look `basic`.**

**The best approach would be to `clearly` state all the variables that you are using in your component into the `data` property. As it will make it easier to understand your component**

**Another Tip:**

Avoid passing the whole object into a method, when handling lists. In your sample code, you are passing the whole `admin` object into the `removeAdmin` method. It would be much easier and faster to use the `index` instead. You can see in my JS fiddle example above how we can handle lists using index, especially with the delete.

When deleting an item, we just used `splice()` and pass the `index` into it. So deleting an item in an array is just as simple as:

```
this.admins.splice(index, 1);
```

But if you will use an object reference, you would need to find the index of that object first in the array which leads you to do an extra step and also slower.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way, this works because I've had the same issue and looked far and wide. Never found solution from anybody.

Create a component file within the v-for, pass the props down and you can add state within the data() or setup() and it will create a new state for each v-for item in the array.